App gateway bicep: Access certificate from kv in another tenant
I have created a bicep for application gateway. It also includes sslCertificate details.
resource secret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2019-09-01' existing = {
  name: '${keyVaultName}/${secretName}'
}

resource applicationGatewaysresource 'Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways@2023-11-01' = {
  name: applicationGatewayName
  location: location
  zones: zones
  properties: {
    sku: {
      name: skuSize
      tier: tier
    }
    gatewayIPConfigurations: [
      {
        name: 'appGatewayIpConfig'
        properties: {
          subnet: {
            id: subnetRef
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    sslCertificates: [
      {
        name: sslCertificateName
        properties: {
          keyVaultSecretId: secret.id
        }
      }
    ]


The issue is that the secret I am referring is from another tenant's subscription. Now I am struggling to figure out a way to refer it.
I will be deploying it using yml pipeline so if there is a way of getting this in pipeline, that will work as well.
Please let me know if the entire app gateway bicep is needed.
Edit 1: The certificate will also be used in httpListeners section of gateway, which as of now looks like
 httpListeners: [
      {
        name: '${appAcronym}${subscriptionName}listener'
        properties: {
          frontendIPConfiguration: {
            id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations', applicationGatewayName, 'appgwpip')
          }
          frontendPort: {
            id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendPorts', applicationGatewayName, 'appgwFEHttpsPort')
          }
          protocol: 'Https'
          sslCertificate: {
            id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/sslCertificates', applicationGatewayName, sslCertificateName)
          }
          hostNames: [
            '*.xyz.com'
          ]
          requireServerNameIndication: true
          customErrorConfigurations: []
        }
      }
    ]


azure lighthouse may needed.

@wenbo Is there no other way to reference the kv in another tenant from bicep? May be using the certificate stored in kv in a variable group? I am trying to find but so far no success :(

Oh, what you said remind me, refering to the keyvault configured in variable group worth a try.

I have already referred it but it is not in the same tenant as app gateway, in which case how do I refer it? Because I need the secret id, any suggestions?

sorry my bad, you actully need the secretId  to fill-in sslCertificates, although this is a string id, but it will call the keyvault in another subscripition managed by acrossed tenant. So if no azure lighthouse integrated will encounter resource not found error. variable group link azure keyvault  in pipeline only help you to get the actual string id or actual secret string, It will not intervene in the template compilation process. What you actually need is a mixed azure context, and one-login can retrieve across tenant subscription resources.

Does your service connection has access to both subscriptions?
If yes you can have a copy step in the build pipeline itself.
Also a deploymentscript would help you to achieve this but it might be more difficult.

Also be aware that to use the certificate you need a managed identity which you don't have in the application gateway bicep you shared.

Thanks wenbo and andrescpacheco for all your help and suggestions. But we have simplified it and keeping the secret in a kv in same tenant.

Just to still answer, I have separate svc connection for both. And yes, I am using a user assigned managed identity but it is not shared here as part of bicep.
